# Higlighting specific texts

Tags: python

I have a python code where I am extracting some texts between some 2 words so when i extracted it will be of three lines or four lines,so i need to highlight a particular texts in the extracted lines.I have tried with some codes like as below

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):     
    return sentence.replace(word, word.upper())  
    
# Example usage 
original_text = "Have a nIcE day, you Nice person!!" 
highlighted_text = highlight_word(original_text, "nice") 
print(highlighted_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that replace is case sensitive. so it would only work on something like

```
original_text = "Have a nice day, you nice person!!"
```

There are many approaches to solve that. However, if you want to highlight the text between the words and not the words themselves, try this:

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):  
    tempSent = sentence.lower()
    tempword = word.lower()
    newSent = ""
    while tempSent.count(tempword)>1 :
        indx1 = tempSent.index(tempword)
        indx2 = tempSent[indx1+1:].index(tempword) + indx1 + len(newSent) + 1
        indx1 += len(newSent) + len(word)
        newSent = newSent+sentence[len(newSent):indx1] + sentence[indx1:indx2].upper() + sentence[indx2:indx2+ len(word)]
        tempSent = sentence[indx2+len(word):].lower()
    newSent = newSent + sentence[indx2+ len(tempword):]
    return newSent
    
# Example usage 
original_text = "Have a nIce day, you nice person!! nice people nice people" 
highlighted_text = highlight_word(original_text, "nice") 
print(original_text)
print(highlighted_text)
```

If you want the word to be highlighted as well just change the indices.
This code uses the word as boundaries for the highlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.compile` to solve this issue.
Here is the sample code

```
import re

def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.sub(word.upper(), sentence)

original_text = "Have a nIcE day, you Nice person!!"
highlighted_text = highlight_word(original_text, "nice")
print(highlighted_text)
```

Sample output:

```
Have a NICE day, you NICE person!!
```

Here is [sample kaggle code](https://www.kaggle.com/heinzmdsiahaan/stof78072060)
More about python regex compile, you can browse [here](https://pynative.com/python-regex-compile/)